# How do I show two html files on one page in a pythonanywhere host website

Tags: html, src, pythonanywhere

Hello I currently have a website hosted on Pythonanywhere and I want to show two html files on one page. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<frameset cols="30%,*">
<frame src="Tablee.html">
<frame src="in.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

I displayed the files by using the render_template function in flask

```
return render_template('2pages.html')
```

It is returning

"The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

I put the html files in the same folder and I do not understand why it is not working. I also checked the spelling of the file names several times. Thanks!

Comment: According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp), the ```frame``` and ```frameset``` tag isn't supported in HTML 5, and that it should be replaced with ```iframe```. Does that help?

Comment: can you show the code you are using to display these files? what web framework are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using flask and I'm displaying the files using the render_template function

Comment: Do you have a route (using the `@app.route` decorator) set up for the URL that you are trying to access?  Flask does not serve up HTML files directly, you need to define the routes in your Python code.

Comment: No I do not. I just did and it's working now! Thanks!